# JPA + Hibernate - Inner Join between parent and child tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

**EDIT (Completely reformulated approach):**

I'm trying to promote the use of JPA in a new project but I'm struggling with a supposedly trivial problem: An INNER JOIN between two tables (parent and child).

I will provide only the essential info and leave all the rest out. Please feel free to ask more info if it's needed. There are two tables LANGUAGE and MESSAGE_RESOURCE, where the parent table is LANGUAGE (Primary Key ID_LANGUAGE) and the child table has a Foreign Key to the parent table also named ID_LANGUAGE.

The Language (parent) class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PF_LANGUAGE")
public class Language {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_LANGUAGE", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idLanguage;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="language",targetEntity=MessageResource.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<MessageResource> messageResources;
}
```

The child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PF_MESSAGE_RESOURCE")
public class MessageResource {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_MESSAGE_RESOURCE", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idMessageResource;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_LANGUAGE")
    private Language language;
}
```

I'm fetching the results with a named query:

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery("select l, r from Language l join l.messageResources r");
```

This results in a result Object array where each entry contains one Language, MessageResource pair. The problem is that this is getting done in separate queries.

I can see in debug output that the first query is an INNER JOIN between both tables, containing the columns from both tables in the output, so this should be enough.
But JPA is doing 2 additional queries (the number of LANGUAGE records) fetching the child table values for each parent table again, which should be not necessary.

First query which is enough to get all data:

```
select
   language0_.ID_LANGUAGE as ID1_5_0_,
   messageres1_.ID_MESSAGE_RESOURCE as ID1_4_1_,
   language0_.CODE as CODE5_0_,
   language0_.DATE_INS  as DATE3_5_0_,
   language0_.DESCRIPTION  as DESCRIPT4_5_0_,
   messageres1_.DATE_INS  as DATE2_4_1_,
   messageres1_.KEY as KEY4_1_,
   messageres1_.ID_LANGUAGE as ID5_4_1_,
   messageres1_.VALUE as VALUE4_1_ 
from
   PF_LANGUAGE language0_ 
inner join
   PF_MESSAGE_RESOURCE messageres1_ 
on language0_.ID_LANGUAGE=messageres1_.ID_LANGUAGE
```

Two redundant queries like the following are also run against the database after the first inner join (they are run once for each LANGUAGE table records):

```
select
    messageres0_.ID_LANGUAGE as ID5_5_1_,
    messageres0_.ID_MESSAGE_RESOURCE as ID1_1_,
    messageres0_.ID_MESSAGE_RESOURCE as ID1_4_0_,
    messageres0_.DATE_INS  as DATE2_4_0_,
    messageres0_.KEY as KEY4_0_,
    messageres0_.ID_LANGUAGE as ID5_4_0_,
    messageres0_.VALUE as VALUE4_0_ 
from
    PF_MESSAGE_RESOURCE messageres0_ 
where
    messageres0_.ID_LANGUAGE=?
```

I need to eliminate the two redundant additional queries generated by JPA. The first inner join is enough to get all data.

Need help with this one. Any clues?

Comment: What's the problem? What behaviour do you want?

Comment: I updated the question info with the desired behaviour being an INNER JOIN, but I though this was implicit by the question title and text flow

Comment: Did you try changing fetch=FetchType.EAGER for messageResources to fetch=FetchType.LAZY ? Since you are explicitly joining, changing FetchType might help.

Comment: @bodunbodun Switching to FetchType.LAZY did the trick. Feel free to write an answer stating that so I can accept it

Comment: Just added as the las answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` for messageResources to `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` 
Since you are explicitly joining, changing `FetchType` to `LAZY` might help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is the actual solution, but my experience with eager fetch is bad.  It is always fetching in some way that I am not expected.

Your query is weird, it doesn't make sense that you are selecting both Language and MessageResource

You may have a try:

Remove `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` in Language's relationship to MessageResource, and change the query to something

```
select l from Language l join fetch l.messageResources where ....
```

It should give you the Language, and the aggregated message resources of that instance, all in one SQL.

Something off-topic, I wonder why you are having MessageResource.language being `insertable=false, updatable=false`.  It seems contradicting as in Language, you specified the relationship mapped by this field but you are now making it non-insertable/updatable.

Comment: I'm getting all the language resources at JVM startup so I want to load them in a single shot using a single inner join without any where clause. About the insertable and updatable attributes nevermind them. I placed them because of duplicate columns complaints of Hibernate/JPA and I already figured out the complain motive and fixed that (ie. removed those attributes). As a final note this query makes sense since I have language key in Language (ie. "en_US", "es_ES") and the key/values in MessageResource (the Resource Bundle support tables are normalized)

Comment: Switching to FetchType.LAZY did the trick but I don't agree with you when you state that this query doesn't make sense (as I explained in my previous comment). I kept the exact same query I was using

Comment: @JavaJuggler in fact my way allows u to do what you are looking for: loading all message resources in single shot.  Since you have mapped the relationship between Language and MessageResource, what you need is you simply get all Language by `from Language l join fetch l.messageResources` and that's all.  Every Language in the result list is having the corresponding list of message resource. What you need to do is just an extra massage of data to any form you want.

Comment: and, in fact in my answer, removing `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` did means changing to lazy fetch as lazy is the default if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why do you expect `inner join` in this case.

`optional = "false"` at `@ManyToOne` means that every `MessageResource` must have a `Language`, but it does not imply that every `Language` must have at least one `MessageResource`, therefore `left join` when loading `Language` is correct in this case - `Language` that you load may have no `MessageResource`s associated with it.

**EDIT:** The purpose of `find()` is to load an object with the given id if it exists in the database. If you want something semantically different (for example, to load all `Language`s that have at least one `MessageResource`), you need to write a query for it, such as `select l from Language l join l.messageResources`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So how should I configure the annotations so I can force it to do an INNER JOIN instead?

Comment: @JavaJuggler: I think you cannot. And why do you need `inner join` in this case, it makes no sense for me?

Comment: There are many reasons for that preference. One of them is the functional difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN. I don't want results where the relationship does not exist. I have serious doubts that JPA does not allow an INNER JOIN between two tables...

Comment: I'm already using the approach you are suggesting of writing queries. I must proceed with the project and can not spend another day researching on this. If there isn't another answer that solves this using only annotations I will mark yours as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a standard way by using standard annotation to force generation of inner query (JPA is a standard and you are using an implementation provider For e.g., Hibernate, TopLink, Open JPA etc). Different JPA implementations use different join strategy. For more details please go through [this](http://victor-ichim.blogspot.in/2012/04/inner-joins-in-jpa.html) and [this](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.in/2010/09/jpa-demystified-episode-1-onetomany-and.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had already read those articles during my research today. They both use "tricks" that I want to avoid. The first one uses JPA-QL / Criteria API. The second one calls Entity Manager using the child instance... I'm surprised an inner join is not straight-forward